# Нужно чтобы бот правильно отвечал пользователю который вводит число. Я создал список из таких чисел, но бот все равно не отвечает

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Я поместил в список числа, при вводе которых пользователем, бот понимал, что ответить. Но по какой то причине ничего не получается. Бот ничего не отвечает

P.s Я новичок в python

```
#main.py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def response(message):
    try:
        filename = 'UserName.json'
        rub = message.text
        if rub == config.scr():
            with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                json.dump(rub, f, ensure_ascii=False)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы переводите ' + rub + ' рублей')

        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите корректную сумму!')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('error')
#config.py
def scr():
    n = 100001
    ls = []
    for i in range(n):
        ls.append(i)
    for elem in ls[:1000]:
        ls.remove(elem)
    array = [str(i) for i in ls]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В `config.py` / `scr` у вас не возвращается список.

   Вместо `array = [str(i) for i in ls]` напишите `return [str(i) for i in ls]`
2. В `config.py` / `response` неправильная проверка наличия числа в списке. У вас проверяется, что введенное значение (строка) равна список.

   Нужно использовать оператор `in`:

   ```
   if rub in config.scr():
   ```
3. Мне кажется проверка диапазона суммы выглядит излишней. Предлагаю математически сравнивать.

   - Тут получаемую сумму пытаемся перевести к целому числу через `int`, если строка не является целым числом, то выбросится исключение ValueError
   - После проверяем что число входит в диапазон от 1 до 1000 (подправьте, если нужен другой диапазон)

   Пример:

   ```
   @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
   def response(message):
       try:
           rub = int(message.text)
           if rub <= 0 or rub > 1000:
               raise ValueError()

           filename = 'UserName.json'
           with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
               json.dump(rub, f, ensure_ascii=False)

           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы переводите {rub} рублей')

       except ValueError:
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите корректную сумму!')

       except FileNotFoundError:
           print('error')
   ```

Comment: gil9red, ОГО! Спасибо вам большое! Теперь все отлично работает! Вы мне очень сильно помогли

Comment: @Cezar369, пожалуйста, смотрели пункт 3.?

Comment: да, но он не работает, вылетает ошибка: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str. Я использовал первый метод, где нужно использовать оператор in

Comment: @Cezar369, да, забыл подправить в сообщении, обновил ответ

Comment: да, теперь он идеально работает! Спасибо вам большое, вы еще и так быстро ответили!

Comment: @Cezar369, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)